# what's wrong with my armature

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, parent

when I parent my armature to my mesh with automatic weights, the mesh deforms and I can't figure out the reason[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, if Crantisz' answer doesn't answer, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Try to select bones in pose mode and press <kbd>alt</kbd> +<kbd>S</kbd> to clear scaling. If you have scaled bones in pose mode, it will affect on the mesh.

Comment: You must mean Alt S?

Comment: Oh, yes, of course

Comment: the scale and rotation are fine. I tried playing with the pole angle too but that wasn't it either. if I go into edit mode, the mesh is fine however if I enter object mode or pose mode, the mesh becomes deformed. also, i noticed if i scale the entire armature down and then parent the mesh, the mesh scales down with the armature. im not sure if that supposed to happen